# Core data and memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm using Core Data, fetching some data into a NSArray and then looping thru it.

```
    ......
    NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSError *error;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {

        ToggleButtonInfo *btn = [[ToggleButtonInfo alloc] init];

        btn.buttonName = [info valueForKey:@"name"];

        [persons addObject:btn];
    }        
    [fetchRequest release];

    return persons;
```

Then I send persons to a component that renders the buttons. In instruments I'm getting the folloging memory leak
[image]

if I replace **btn.buttonName = [info valueForKey:@"name"];** with **btn.buttonName = @"something else";** the leak despairs. Notice that NSSQLCore. The leaks increments every time I call this method to refresh the view. I want to mention that the "Person" table has a relationship with another table, one-to-many. In the component, when I'm about to load new data, I release the NSMutableArray, and it doesn't look to be the problem. should I release something else here? what am I missing?

UPDATE *******************************************
here is a screenshot of Instruments. It looks like the custom objects are ben released correctly. the problem is associated with Core Data, doesn't it?
[image]
.. and going into the NSString:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Build and Analyze? This should help you track down things like memory leaks.

Comment: I just ran it, no issues. that's crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memory leak, at its most basic, is an unbalanced retain. Where you get the object **from** doesn't matter nearly as much as what you do with it while it is alive.

Based on the code you've shared, my best guess would be that the buttonName property is being over-retained by ToggleButtonInfo. You should study carefully the lifespan of ToggleButtonInfo's buttonName property. Are you releasing it properly in ToggleButtonInfo's dealloc?

Showing more code would help.

Comment: totally right. sometimes the easiest is very difficult to see. Thanks Steven

Comment: Glad to help. I'm constantly surprised at just how often Apple's tools *actually tell me what the problem is*. It's not something I'm used to. At all. :)

Answer (score 2):

Going through your code, I see a few places where you call `alloc`. Whenever you call `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`, you must call `release` or `autorelease`. I suggest changing `NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to `NSMutableArray *persons = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];`.

Autoreleased objects are guaranteed to be available for the duration of the method call.

Also, a quick suggestion: You should check out `Build and analyze` from the `Build` menu if you haven't.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I'm releasing that NSMutableArray in the method where I call this code from. Would that have the same effect of do you recommend to use autorelease instead?

Comment: releasing an object immediately when you are done with it is the best way to go, because autorelease does not always happen immediately, but you have no choice when returning an object.

Comment: ok, I did it. thanks for the suggestion. I'm still getting the leak. Why does it point to NSSQLCore? should I release "info" in any way? when I execute "valueForkey" is something been created that I need to release?

Comment: It is possible that Apple's classes are leaking. If that is the case, then you can't do much about it.

Comment: Oh! You have to release `btn`.

Comment: I'm releasing btn in another method. if I replace btn.buttonName = [info valueForKey:@"name"]; with btn.buttonName = @"something else"; the leak despairs.

Comment: Why are releasing btn elsewhere? Are you releasing it twice there? Just curious.

Comment: well, I may be doing it wrong. Here's why. I'm sending btn (ToggleButtonInfo) to a component, that component extends UIScrollView. This component creates/adds subview to itself based on the information provided by this method (here in the question). Each subview is a custom component that extends UIButton to add some functionality and ALSO store **btn**. So, if I use autorelease here, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to pass in **btn** to each subview. If there is a better way to do it, I will be happy to hear it. Tks.

Comment: Try objectForKey instead. See if you can release that once you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to explain your finding with respect to **[info valueForKey:@"name"]** versus **@"something else"**, but it does look like you are leaking btn. After **[persons addObject:btn];** you should have **[btn release];**

Adding btn to NSMutableArray persons will increment btn's retain count (until it is removed from persons). But -alloc returns btn with retain count of 1, making your method its owner.

Comment: I get an error if I do the release after addObject. isn't that normal because the NSMutableArray owns the objects after it is added?

Comment: NSMutableArray's addObject should increment retain count, thus "owning" added object (btn). At that point you should be able to call release on btn without btn getting deallocated. What error do you get?

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: You should use NSZombieEnabled. See 'Finding Memory Leaks' section at end of <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html > for details. This is the *best* way to discover what object is being accessed after having been deleted/deallocated. The post-dealloc access will be logged in debug console.

Comment: If he was leaking the entire button, he'd have a bigger leak.

Comment: True, but btn isn't an entire button. It is just an instance of ToggleButtonInfo. Granted 'btn' is a slightly misleading name.

Comment: By bigger I didn't mean "much bigger," only "bigger than a NSString." But to be fair, probably "different than a NSString" would have been more accurate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your return line be?

```
return [persons autorelease];
```